# How to sort a column based on two critera in excel in a formula?

Tags: excel, sorting, dynamic, excel-formula

How can I sort the ISINs below based on CCY and Maturity in a formula (without a datatable) dynamically so that I can still drag down the formula?

ISIN    Maturity    CCY

ID1 01.01.2018  USD

ID2 31.01.2018  USD

ID3 02.03.2018  USD

ID4 01.04.2018  USD

ID5 01.05.2018  CHF

ID6 31.05.2018  JPY

ID7 30.06.2018  CHF

ID8 30.07.2018  AUD

ID9 29.08.2018  AUD

Many thanks
Clemens

I have already tried the rank formula which allows to sort the columns individually but not to reference back to the ISIN column again.

Comment: So what do you try exactly. CCY on a-z and maturity on date? Then report back ISIN?

Comment: please explain what do you mean by `without a datatable`? If this is the list of source data, please post another list of expected outcome. Also please share what you have tried or searched online if possible. Having these said, why can't you just use the `custom sort` function to sort the data as desired?

Comment: Create an auxiliar column with CCY&Maturity and sort it, so you will get your data sorted. If you need to order by Maturity&CCY, then change the order. But please, `"I have already tried the rank formula which allows to sort the columns individually but not to reference back to the ISIN column again."` means that you have your code, so, next time, provide it.